# find cousins in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [993. Cousins in Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/cousins-in-binary-tree/description/):

> Given the `root` of a binary tree with unique values and the values of two different nodes of the tree `x` and `y`, return `true` *if the nodes corresponding to the values* `x` *and* `y` *in the tree are **cousins**, or* `false` *otherwise*.
>
> Two nodes of a binary tree are cousins if they have the same depth with different parents.
>
> Note that in a binary tree, the root node is at the depth `0`, and children of each depth `k` node are at the depth `k + 1`.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - The number of nodes in the tree is in the range `[2, 100]`.
> - `1 <= Node.val <= 100`
> - Each node has a **unique** value.
> - `x != y`
> - `x` and `y` are exist *[sic]* in the tree.

#### My attempt

I made a `height` function which returns the height of a node from root and I checked the heights of both X and Y.
If they are different I returned false.
Then I made a parent function  which returns the parent of  a node. Then I checked if the parents are same return false else return true.

```cpp
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
 
int height(TreeNode* root,int x){
    if(root==NULL)
        return -1;
    if(root->val==x)
        return 1;
    int lh=height(root->left,x);
    int rh=height(root->right,x);

    if(lh!=-1)
        return lh+1;
    if(rh!=-1)
        return rh+1;
    
     return -1;
}

TreeNode* parent(TreeNode* root,int x){
    if(!root)
        return NULL;
    if(root->right && root->right->val==x )
        return root;
    if(root->left && root->left->val==x)
        return root;
    TreeNode* lh=parent(root->left,x);
    TreeNode* rh=parent(root->right,x);   
    if(!lh)
        return lh;
    if(!rh)
        return rh;
    
        return NULL;
}

class Solution {
public:
    bool isCousins(TreeNode* root, int x, int y) {
        //check if height of both are same
        int xh=height(root,x);
        int yh=height(root,y);
        if(xh!=yh)
            return 0;

        ///check if parents of both are same
        TreeNode* xp=parent(root,x);
        TreeNode* yp=parent(root,y);
        if(xp==yp)
            return 0;
        
        return 1;
    }
};
```

#### Problem

I get the wrong result for this example input:

[image]

- Input: `root = [1,2,3,null,4,null,5]`, `x = 5`, `y = 4`
- Expected Output: `true`

... but my code returns `false`. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in the `parent` function.

This group of statements will always return `NULL`:

```cpp
    if(!lh)
        return lh;
    if(!rh)
        return rh;
    
        return NULL;
```

You'll want to return a Node reference when it is *not* `NULL`. So correct to this:

```cpp
    if (lh)
        return lh;
    if (rh)
        return rh;
    
    return NULL;
```